# SSLHandshake Exception in SoapUI

Tags: soapui, apache-axis, sslhandshakeexception

I am getting SSL Handshake exception calling a web service using the Axis framework. I can browse to the wsdl file with no issues. 
I have added the ssl certificate into cacert trust store and added the cacert into my project

My Soapui options file looks like as below

```
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40
-Xms128m
-Xmx1000m
-Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties
-Dsoapui.home=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin
-Dsoapui.ext.libraries=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/ext
 -Dsoapui.ext.listeners=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/listeners
-Dsoapui.ext.actions=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/actions
-Dwsi.dir=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/wsi-test-tools
-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
-splash:SoapUI-Spashscreen.png
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by copying the security policy file from

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

and copying the jar files to

C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\jre\lib\security